# Label not displaying full text swift

Tags: ios, swift, label

I set up label programmatically and want to change the text of the label once a button is clicked. However, the label just displays part of the text. For example, I want to change the text from "press to start a trip" to "searching for GPS signal..", only "searching for" displayed even without "..." to indicate that there are more texts.

```
let startTravelBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 50, width: 50,
```

height: 30))

```
let startTipLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 50, width: 200, height: 30))
```

Comment: Set Lines = 0 of Label and remove fixed width constraint if its provided to label.

Comment: Add the code you're using to set up the label programmatically

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should always post the code you try and add screenshots if needed.

Comment: set number of lines to 0 and after assigning the text call `label.sizeToFit().`

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

```
yourLabel.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing"
yourLabel.sizeToFit()
```

**OR**

Set Lines on label to 0

Comment: If you are using this approach then make sure you don't give height constraint

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting `numberOfLines` to `0`

```
 startTipLabel.text = "longer text what you want"
 startTipLabel.numberOfLines = 0
 startTipLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = PaddingLabel(withInsets: 10, 10, 10, 10)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue Light", size: 17)
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.sizeToFit()
```

(label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping) - doesn't also work

I tried many methods As a result, only this method
(label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true) helps to avoid hiding the text.